# centering element in div that is already centered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website using html, css, JavaScript and php. in the website I have a navigation bar that has three links on it. a games tab, a consoles tab and a accessories tab in that order. when I try to spread the a tags evenly, the consoles tag doesn't appear in the middle while everything lese on the page does. here is a screenshot of my website

[image: screenshot of my website]

and here is the current code i have:

the html

```
<ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="games.php">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="consoles.php">Consoles</a></li>
        <li><a href="accessories.php">Accessories</a></li>
</ul>
```

the css

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;

    padding: 0% 1%;
    
    
    list-style: none;
    background-color: var(--secondary-highlight-colour);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}

.navbar li {
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar li a {
    color: var(--background-black);
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

i have tried changing the justify content to spread evenly and around but that didnt change anything

any help is greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Use justify-content: space-between

Comment: @GetSet i tried thst nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to initialize the margins of each tag manually. If the width of the main(pink or maybe purple!) div has a specific amount, then you can calculate the gap between each tag and consider an amount for the margin attributes of each of them. On the other hand, if the width is set to 100% (or possibly not included in the main div class), then you should try different amounts for the margin attributes of each tag.
Here's a css code in which width attribute is not included:

```
.main{
display: flex;
text-align: center;
background: red;
height: auto;
color: white;
font-size: 70px;
}

.main div:first-child{
margin-left: 170px;
}

.main div:nth-child(2){
margin-left: 200px;
margin-right: 70px;
}

.main div:last-child{
margin-right: 50px;
}
```